# Join on Table Variable if it has data

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure that accepts a user defined table type, which is just a list of ints.

If the table is not set (Either sent in as NULL, or has no rows), then my existing query to return data is OK. But I need to only return Ids that are in that table variable.

So if the table variable has data, I would like to INNER JOIN on it, to only return matching Ids.

So that the moment, it's a basic query like this: (Example)

```
SELECT ...
FROM MyTable
Where UserId = 1
```

But I need to somehow:

```
SELECT ...
FROM MyTable m
INNER JOIN @MyTableVariable v ON v.Id = m.Id, --But only if @MyTableVariable  has data
Where UserId = 1
```

Can I do the inner join, only when there's data in @MyTableVriable? Or maybe EXITSTS would help?

Comment: Can you clarify - when the table variable is empty then you want to return ALL "MyTable" rows (that match the WHERE clause), but if it contains data then only those "MyTable" values with matching "Id" should be returned (along with the WHERE clause)?

Comment: Yup @Craig - That's correct.

Comment: I would just use `IF..ELSE` statement, check for `exists` of rows in `@MyTableVariable` and execute the query accordingly

Comment: I am trying "INNER JOIN @MyTableVariable t ON t.Id = t.Id OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @MyTableVariable)" - But when my MyTableVariable  is empty, I get no results, when I'd expect to get them all.

Comment: I would do it as two separate queries with `IF`. But if you really want one query then `WHERE (m.Id IN (SELECT v.Id FROM @MyTableVariable v) OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @MyTableVariable))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, a relatively simple approach (assuming your SELECT statement is not too complicated and you don't mind "duplicating" it) would be:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @MyTableVariable)
BEGIN
    SELECT ...
    FROM MyTable m
    INNER JOIN @MyTableVariable v ON v.Id = m.Id, --But only if @MyTableVariable  has data
    Where UserId = 1;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT ...
    FROM MyTable m
    Where UserId = 1;
END
```

Otherwise

```
SELECT ...
FROM MyTable m
LEFT OUTER JOIN @MyTableVariable v ON v.Id = m.Id, --But only if @MyTableVariable  has data
Where UserId = 1
AND
(
    (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @MyTableVariable)
         AND v.Id Is Not NULL)
    OR
    (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @MyTableVariable))
);
```

I'll stand corrected if I'm wrong (just don't have the opportunity to test it myself right now), but I believe that even if NULL was passed in as the @MyTableVariable value, SQL would still see it as an empty table (with the corresponding structure of the UDT)

Comment: That does work, @Craig -I'll check the query plan, but it's a tiny amount of data, and your answer is pretty readable.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server provides conditional statemets; then, you can try this approach bellow, with a conditional select, based on your table variable status (in this example, checking if is not empty):

```
IF(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @MyTableVariable))
BEGIN
   SELECT ...
   FROM MyTable m
   INNER JOIN @MyTableVariable v ON v.Id = m.Id
   WHERE UserId = 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   SELECT ...
   FROM MyTable
   WHERE UserId = 1
END
```